# PowerBI - calculate amount of rows depending on values in multiple columns

Tags: function, powerbi, dax

*PowerBi Desktop v 2.64.5285.741 64-bit (November 2018)*

Hello,

Imagine I have a table called **WorkReport**

[image]

In PowerBi Desktop, what would be the correct DAX syntax for finding the amount of rows that contains both `Status = 'Not Started'` and `Progress = "slow"`?

Below I will provide a list of queries that I've unsuccessfully tried:

`report = CALCULATE(COUNTAX(WorkReport,WorkReport[Status]),
WorkReport[Status] = "Not Started") &&
WorkReport[progress]WorkReport[progress], WorkReport[progress] =
"slow")`

`report = CALCULATE(COUNT(WorkReport,WorkReport[Status]),
WorkReport[Status] = "Not Started") &&
WorkReport[progress]WorkReport[progress], WorkReport[progress] =
"slow")`

`report = CALCULATE(COUNTAX(WorkReport,WorkReport[Status]),
WorkReport[Status] = "Not Started") AND
WorkReport[progress]WorkReport[progress], WorkReport[progress] =
"slow")`

`report = CALCULATE(COUNT(WorkReport,WorkReport[Status]),
WorkReport[Status] = "Not Started") AND
WorkReport[progress]WorkReport[progress], WorkReport[progress] =
"slow")`

`report = COUNTROWS(FILTER(WorkReport,WorkReport[Status]="NotStarted")
AND (WorkReport, WorkReport[progress] = "slow"))`

`report = COUNTROWS(FILTER(WorkReport,WorkReport[Status]="NotStarted")
&& (WorkReport, WorkReport[progress] = "slow"))`

[image]
[image]

Please advise if you were able to achieve this in PowerBI Desktop tool. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The measure itself is a simple `COUNTROWS`, but you need to use `CALCULATE` to transition the context, applying the filters you want:

```
MyMeasure = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        COUNTROWS ( WorkReport ),
        WorkReport[Status] = "Not Started",
        WorkReport[Progress] = "slow"
    )
```

Comment: thanks, your solution worked for me really good, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, but your syntax is a bit off. Try this one:

```
report =
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        WorkReport,
        WorkReport[Status] = "NotStarted" &&
        WorkReport[progress] = "slow"
    )
)
```

Comment: thanks for the response. But instead of showing only 3 rows that match the filter criteria, the query returns 21. Not sure why. I attached the screenshot to the original question above.

Comment: That's because you created it as a calculated column and then put that into a visual using an implicit sum measure. Define it as a measure instead of a calculated column, and it should work fine.

Comment: You can vote up both answers, but it doesn't appear that you've accepted either.